# Problem with Z-Indexing with CreateCanvas() Function & SVG / WEBGL

Tags: javascript, svg, canvas, webgl

Im trying to make a BG element with p5.js (Shader) using WEBGL with an SVG over it. I have the positioning right, however, the p5 sketch sits on top of the SVG despite z-indexing that element. Any thoughts? There are .frag and .vert files but im keeping them out as it adds a ton of code.

```
// HTML
<body>
<header>
      <svg>
            ....///...
      </svg>
 </header>
 <div id="header_sketch"></div>
</body>

/// CSS

header {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 200;
}

#header_sketch {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    z-index: -200;
}

/// JS 

let theShader;

function preload() {
    theShader = loadShader('shader.vert', 'shader.frag');
}

function setup() {
    pixelDensity(1);
    let myCanvas = createCanvas(windowWidth, windowHeight, WEBGL);
    myCanvas.parent('header_sketch');
}

function draw() {
    shader(theShader);
    theShader.setUniform("u_resolution", [width, height]);
    theShader.setUniform("u_time", millis() / 1000.0);
    theShader.setUniform("u_mouse", [mouseX, map(mouseY, 0, height, height, 0)]);
    rect(0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0);
}


function windowResized() {
    resizeCanvas(windowWidth, windowHeight);
}
```

Comment: There is no `#header_sketch` element.  Please create a [mcve] so we can better see what is happening.

Comment: Thanks Paul. Im new to posting so thank you for the tip ... I put that div in.

Comment: Please create a minimal working example, as a StackOverflow Snippet, Codepen, etc, that demonstrates the issue.

Comment: Rather than using `z-index`, just change the order of the elements; put the `div` before the `header`